# Python arrow "->" return type hints in functions that return two lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, type-hinting, pep8

I'm updating python functions to have a return type and this function is causing issues:

```
def split_x_and_y( data_packet ) -> list[float], list[Union[float, str]]:
    ### theres some logic and operations here
    x_values = data_packet.x # this is the 1st return type of list[float]
    y_values = data_packet.y # this is the 2nd return type of list[Union[float, str]]
    ### theres some logic and operations here
    return x_values, y_values
```

Which is what I'm trying to do, but this line:

```
def split_x_and_y( data_packet ) -> list[float], list[Union[float, str]]:
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Is throwing syntax errors. Even VSCode doesn't appreciate the comma between the two type hint return lists. What is the correct way to write a return type hint for two, three, or even four different items (that have various return hints)?

My function `split_x_and_y` should return two Lists. For this example sake, there's A LOT more that goes into the `data_packet.x` and `data_packet.y`, so `List[...]` is just a placeholder. Suppose that the first return is a `list` of `floats` and the second being a `list` of either `floats` or `strings`.

In the many places this function is called, its called like this:

```
my_x, my_y = split_x_and_y( data_packet )
```

I don't think Unions are the solution, unfortunately. I have two items to return, not just two return types. I looked at several online resources, including stackoverflow, and couldn't find an example to what I'm looking for. Is this even kosher python anymore? Some of these functions are fairly old.

I could always split up the function, but it would require a refactoring of several key components, and this was supposed to be a very minimal change (simply just adding type hints).

Comment: you have to import List from typing and then you will be able to do List[Union[int, float]]

Comment: It doesn't return two lists; it returns a single *tuple* that contains two lists.

Comment: @AdrienDerouene `list` has been generic for years; `typing.List` is deprecated.

Comment: Use `Tuple[list[float], list[float]]`. You're not returning two lists but rather a tuple of two lists. Python's syntax sugar hides this nuance